Why Javascript dblclick event is running at Chrome but isn't running at the Edge?
I am new to the javascript. I want to double click a button and write something to the console but the code I use doen't work.
The code here: btn.addEventListener("dblclick",function);
This code didn't work at the Microsoft Edge. I looked the documentation. At the documentation there are two way.
First way is (this way is same with my way):
addEventListener("dblclick", (event) => {});
Second way is:
ondblclick = (event) => {};
I tried two way but it didn't work. And than I changed 'dblclick' to 'ondblclick' but it didn't work again. But at this times I didn't take any error or warning. At the last time I tried at the Google Chrome it worked successfully.
Why the same code worked at the Chrome but didn't work at the Edge? What can I do to solve this problem?

What's supposed to happen when you double click? Pleased [edit] your question to include a [mre]. Current your code doesn't execute any code upon double-clicking for any browser. It could be that your callback function is failing.

If you actually put some code in the function it should work, e.g. (event) => {console.log("double clicked");}

^ @MisterJojo That comment seems to be only critical/unhelpful. Pressing a button twice in rapid succession to indicate a unique intent is quite prevalent in both software and physical experiences (e.g. phone button, gamepad, etc.). Presumably, anyone who is reaching for the dblclick event is either unfamiliar with debounce timing or isn't interested in supplying an implementation.

@Tulgar Can you [edit] your question to include [mre]? Here's an example demonstrating how to listen for the event on a button and update the DOM in response.

If you have a code like you mentioned, btn.addEventListener("dblclick", function);, then "function" is a reserved word, so you can't name your function that way. But since your code ran, I assume it was just an example.
So, I suggest you check whether you are actually getting the button to which you want to attach the event listener.
HTML
<button id="btn">Hello button</button>

JS
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
console.log(btn); // Check if the element is retrieved

btn.addEventListener("dblclick", (event) => console.log("Hello world!"));

If you're not getting the element, it might be because your script is running before the HTML is fully loaded. This is a common mistake for beginners. The <script src="file.js"> tag should be placed at the end of the <body> element.
<body>
  <button id="btn">Hello button</button>

  <script src="file.js"></script>
</body>

You can check which features are not supported in different browsers here:
Can I use.
However, in your case, double-click events are supported in both Edge and Chrome.
